# Remote desktop is disabled on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I've purchased new Asus Zenbook laptop with Windows 10 Pro. 
Now I can't turn on RDP - it is available, but disabled for selection.
Laptop is in enterprise domain, has internet connection (wifi). All Windows updates are installed.

[image]

[image: image - Windows Version]

Comment: So your computer is part of a domain? Speak to IT team

Comment: We don't have "IT team" - that is why I asked question here. Actually, I got it solved by using Windows 10 native settings window (kind of metro-style). But none of ours Win10 machines have same issue btw.

Comment: Go to gpedit.msc and set the `Allow users to connect remotely by using Remote Desktop Services` to enabled.

Comment: So this is no longer requires an answer?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using Windows 10 "native" (not classic) settings window:

*Settings - System - Remote desktop - Enable Remote desktop* 
(something like that, I translated this from russian)

or in russian:

*Параметры - Система - Удаленный рабочий стол - Включить удаленный рабочий стол*

[image]

P.S. Classic window still blocks RDP options, but it works.